# Share Files between Aws lambda and EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want a solution to share files between AWS Lambda and EC2 **(Windows)**.

How can lambda place the file inside the ec2 file system after it notifies by the s3event? In the same way, if way lambda wants to access the ec2 file system that also should be possible.

For example: if any file created in s3 will trigger notify lambda, then that would be copied to EC2 drive in some path, then application inside server will process it and so on.

Please let me know any possible way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to achieve? If your goal is to process a file on Amazon S3, then a better architecture would be for S3 to push a message onto an Amazon SQS queue, and a worker on the EC2 instance should poll the queue. Or, if you want the file processed by an AWS Lambda function, there is no need for an EC2 instance. Please Edit your question to tell us _what_ you are wanting to achieve, rather than _how_.

Comment: True. But the existing old application is written in the .NET framework using Office Interop (and some other dll) and it is looking into some specific folder for any file processing it with some operation like content creating, execution macros, etc.,Now the source files are moving to S3. If it is possible to copy the source file whenever created in s3 to the local drive the existing application will take care of the operation. And I don't need to modify the existing system.

Comment: You could just create a Scheduled Task on the Windows machine to run the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 
sync` command to automatically copy any new files from S3 to a local directory. Not great if you have thousands of files amassed in S3 or locally. Or, use a utility such as tntdrive.com, [Cloudberry Drive](https://www.msp360.com/drive/amazon-s3.aspx) or [Expandrive](https://www.expandrive.com/s3-drive-mac-windows/) to mount S3 as a drive (similar to Dropbox).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks simple to achieve instead of going with services like Lambda function, SQS to write new codes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/index.html). This is a network file system which can be simultaneously mounted on EC2 instance as well as within Lambda functions.

As the process is quite lengthy, and the question didn't mention which OS is being used (EFS is not supported on Windows), or what Lambda runtime is desirable. Its impractical to document a full example, however there are some useful guides to get started.

There is a blog on using [EFS within Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) functions. The Lambda function would need access to read the object from the S3 bucket and store it on the EFS volume.

An example of [mounting EFS on an EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html) instance running Amazon Linux also exists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will go through the shared details. When I searching for solutions, I came through EFS and came to know that it is not supported in Windows from the documents. That's why I added EC2 (Windows) in bold in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your S3 send a notification event when an object is created.

In your lambda function set up a S3 trigger that consumes s3 notification events - checkout this tutorial: [Using an Amazon S3 trigger to invoke a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Then you probably would want your lambda to call an endpoint on your EC2 service to trigger the copy function, or source the event in a message broker like SQS if you care about real-time processing.

Comment: Yes, I can able to achieve the triggering part. When an object is created in s3 it triggers my Lambda function and getting object details. Also, a temporary solution was tried with the SQS service, where the application inside the server will check for a new event queue triggered by s3 and be able to get.

But looking for some solution where I can place the file directly into the EC2 file system directly without any service hosted in the server (because it considering one more application to run inside the server additionally).

Comment: OK, if you don't mind answering the following, 1) when you say another application, do you mean that you want to avoid pushing events to that application by design?, 2) is the file a one-time usage like configuration or is it part of a business pipeline?. 3) what is the type, estimated size and purpose of this file?.